# Kodaira-Spencer morphism - complete deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$, $T$ be smooth varieties over $\mathbb C$, $X$ projective, and $\mathcal E$ a coherent sheaf on $X\times T$, flat on $T$. Let $t_0\in T$ be a closed point. Suppose that all the sheaves ${\mathcal E}_t$, $t\in T$, are different (i.e. ${\mathcal E}_t$ and ${\mathcal E}_{t'}$ are not isomorphic if $t\not=t'$), and that
$$\dim(T)=dim(
Ext^1({\mathcal E}_{t_0},{\mathcal E}_{t_0})) .$$
Does this implies that $\mathcal E$ is a complete (or semi-universal) deformation of ${\mathcal E}_{t_0}$ ?

Comment: I don't think so, basically for the reason that a surjective morphism doesn't have to have surjective differential at every point--e.g. you can have branched coverings.  For example say $S\to T$ is a branched covering of smooth curves, then we can pull back $E$ to $X \times S$.  The Kodaira-Spencer map for the family on $S$ will factor as the differential of $S\to T$ and the Kodaira-Spencer map for the family on $T$.  This is then 0 at a ramification point.

Comment: On the other hand in characterstic zero I believe it will be true that the family is complete for general $t$ if $T$ is irreducible.  In characteristic $p$, using the Frobenius, it should be possible to make the Kodaira-Spencer map be zero everywhere.

Comment: @Jack Huizenga   In your example, if $\mathcal F$ is the pull back of $\mathcal E$ to $X\times S$, the property "all the sheaves ${\mathcal F}_s$, $s\in S$, are different" is no longer true.

Comment: True.  It seems though that you should be able to take a family of sheaves parameterized by a cuspidal curve and pull back to the normalization and the same argument will apply.  Another perspective is that you can have a 1-parameter family of different sheaves which gives a trivial first-order deformation but nontrivial higher order deformations.

Comment: I think that it will work if we assume that all the trace maps  $$Ext^2({\mathcal E}_t,{\mathcal E}_t)\to H^2({\mathcal O}_X)$$ are bijective, and all the $Ext^1({\mathcal E}_t,{\mathcal E}_t)$ have the same dimension as $T$.

Comment: If you assume $E_{t_0}$ is stable and that the moduli space of stable sheaves is smooth at this point, then I think Zariskis Main Theorem will tell you that the map from a neighborhood of $t_0$ to the moduli space will be a local isomorphism, and completeness follows near $t_0$.  I am not sure how necessary these extra assumptions are.

Comment: I would rather go in the opposite direction: given the above properties, prove that $T$ is a kind of moduli space (with appropriate definitions). The problem is that we have nice semi-universal deformations, but only in analytic geometry I think.